# Bug in UWP or am I missing something

Tags: c#, events, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm starting my first Universal Windows app.  First thing I wanted was to subclass the main "Page" class for navigation.  For simple purposes, I wanted to just add a RightTapped event hook to display a message of the actual page displayed...

Anyhow, I created a brand new project.  Created a single class MyPage

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        RightTapped += MyPage_RightTapped;
    }

    private async void MyPage_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("This page is " + GetType(), "What is my form");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Then on the default main form, I changed MainPage.xaml from

```
<Page
```

to

```
<local:MyPage
```

In the codebehind, I changed

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
```

to

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
```

Run the form, it works, right-click on keyboard and message comes up.

Now the problem.  In the main page, at the Grid declaration, it is define with a background...

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

If I remove this color (the actual color default is "#FFFFFFFF")

```
<Grid>
```

the RightTapped even no longer works and this is the ONLY change.  I put in a background of any other color and RightTapped works.

Can anyone explain this and why it fails without background color which should not have any bearing vs working with a background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it's documented behavior. The documentation for [UIElement.RightTapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.righttapped.aspx) contains some relevant hints:

> For touch actions and also for interaction-specific or manipulation events that are consequences of a touch action, an element must be hit-test visible in order to be the event source and fire the event that is associated with the action. [**UIElement.Visibility**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.visibility.aspx) must be [**Visible**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visibility.aspx). Other properties of derived types also affect hit-test visibility. For more info, see [**Events and routed events overview**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185584.aspx#hit_testing).

And the details from [Events and routed events overview: Hit testing and input events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#hit-testing-and-input-events):

> There are several factors that affect hit testing, but you can determine whether a given element can fire input events by checking its [**IsHitTestVisible**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208933) property. This property returns **true** only if the element meets these criteria:
>
> - The element's [**Visibility**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208992) property value is [**Visible**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209006).
> - The element's **Background** or **Fill** property value is not **null**. A **null[Brush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br228076)** value results in transparency and hit test invisibility. (To make an element transparent but also hit testable, use a [**Transparent**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh748061) brush instead of **null**.)

The [Grid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242704)'s [Background property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel.background) (inherited from [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel)) defaults to **null**, making the Grid without a *Background* XAML attribute invisible to hit-testing.